# Convergence of iterates to a local minimizer for a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable convex scalar-valued function where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and all sublevel sets of $f$ are bounded. Let $(x_k)$ be a sequence such that $x_{k+1}=x_k-\gamma \nabla f(x_k)$ for some suitable $\gamma>0$ so $(f(x_k))$ is nonincreasing. The suitable $\gamma$ is at most $2/L$ where $L$ is the Lipschitz modulus of the gradient, i.e., $\|\nabla f(y)- \nabla f(x)\| \leq L\|y-x\|$.

Is it possible to show that $(x_{k_j})$ a subsequence of $(x_k)$ converges to some local minimum of $x^*$, i.e., $x^{k_j} \to x^*$ or $\|x^{k_j} - x^*\|_2 \to 0$.

Observe that we say some local minimum since a convex $f(x)$ may have multiple local minimizers. For example, $f(x)=\|Ax-b\|_2^2$ for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ where $m< n$ and $b \in \text{Range}(A)$ there are infinitely many local minimizers.

**My try**

In order to show $(x_{k_j})$ is convergent, I need to show it is bounded and I do not know how to show it. I only have access to $f(y) \geq f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), y-x \rangle$ and do not know how to utilize it for my purpose.

Comment: (It is not entirely clear what you are asking. ) If I understand your question, it is not possible without extra conditions. Take $f(x) = e^{-x}$ and $x_n = 1-{1 \over n}$.

Comment: If $f$ is convex, **all** minimisers are global.

Comment: @copper.hat: I should have added all sublevel sets are bounded to avoid any confusion. I will edit the question.

Comment: The same would apply to $f(x) = (x-2)^2$.

Comment: @copper.hat: I will add $x_{k+1}=x_k-\gamma \nabla f(x_k)$. Would this work?

Comment: Why don't you edit the question and ask the question you want? After  a few years it gets a little tiring to chase questions down.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: You need to do some work. More conditions are needed, if $f(x) = {1 \over 2} x^2$ with $\gamma = 2$ then starting at $x_0 = 1$ will give the sequence $+1,-1,+1,-1,...$.

Comment: I mentioned suitable $\gamma$. The one you are considering is not right since it is not suitable. The suitable one is at most $2/L$ where $L$ is the Lipschitz modulus of the gradient, i.e., $\|\nabla f(y)- \nabla f(x)\| \leq L\|y-x\|$. In the case you have the maximum $\gamma$ should be 1.

Comment: Describing it as suitable is a little vague.

Comment: You can show that every accumulation point $x^*$ of $(x_k)$ satisfies $\nabla f(x^*)=0$. This should follow more or less directly from the calculation to find the suitable $\gamma$. Just sum the resulting inequality wrt $k$.

Comment: @daw: I can show that but how I can show that a sequence of iterates converges?

Answer (score 1):

From the Lipschitz continuity of $\nabla f$, one gets
$$
f(y) \le f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x) + \frac L2\|y-x\|^2.
$$
For the special choice $y:=x-\gamma \nabla f(x)$ this means
$$
f(x-\gamma \nabla f(x)) \le f(x) - \gamma \|\nabla f(x)\|^2 + \frac{\gamma^2L}2 \|\nabla f(x)\|^2,
$$
so that
$$
f(x-\gamma \nabla f(x)) \le f(x) - \gamma (1-\frac{\gamma L}2) \|\nabla f(x)\|^2.
$$
Applying this inequality to the iterates, yields
$$
f(x_{k+1})  +  \gamma (1-\frac{\gamma L}2) \|\nabla f(x_k)\|^2 \le f(x_k) .
$$
Due to $\gamma < L/2$, the sequence $(f(x_k))$ is monotonically increasing.
Since level sets of $f$ are bounded, $(x_k)$ has a convergent subsequence, $x_{k_j}\to x^*$. In addition, $f(x_k)$ has a convergent subsequence, and is thus convergent. Now $\nabla f(x^*)=0$ follows from
$$
0 \le \gamma (1-\frac{\gamma L}2) \|\nabla f(x_k)\|^2 \le f(x_k)- f(x_{k+1}) \to0.
$$

Comment: You are showing that gradient converges to zero. You are not showing $\|x_{k_j}-x^*\|\to 0$. I think the proof is not complete since it misses the part that the gradient of every accumulation point of $(x_k)$ should be zero.

Comment: ? I proved that *every* accumulation point of $(x_k)$ has zero gradient. If $x^*$ is an accumulation point then $\|x_{k_j}-x^*\|\to 0$ by definition.